# Why number or digits showing dots on smartphone?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, ms-clarity

I am facing one issue. My whole website digits change to "…" dots. Example if there is "123", it changes to "…".

Here is my deployed application: https://ezylegal.in/legal-consultation

**On mobile view**
[image]

It is showing `100` lawyers online. But I am checking user experience using Microsoft clarity. It is showing "…" dots on user phone.

Example
https://clarity.microsoft.com/shared/recording/746798c1-ed2b-4171-8371-5d024d65f176
[image]

Any suggestion why it is showing dots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s because Microsoft Clarity hides all sensitive data by default (or the data *it thinks* is sensitive). It’s called masking content.

> Clarity masks all sensitive content on your website by default. The sensitive content includes all input box content, numbers, and email addresses. Clarity doesn't capture masked content.

So **it will include any numbers on your page by default**. More information about (un)masking content and the source of the quote above, you can find on the [Clarity docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/clarity/clarity-masking).

Comment: but some videos it is showing the digits

Comment: @Naveen That’s not mentioned in your question. I do not know the strictness of the masking settings. You can try different settings shown in the documentation.